# TeX and Hyper text links

Tags: macros, hyperref, dvips

I am a TeX (not LaTeX) user (and a member of UK TeX user group) of many years and produce macros for maths and complex tables.  I include some hyper text links within a document using the Y&Y `dvipsone` and their `\special{button:` ... and `\special{mark:`.
...

`dvipsone` is no longer supported, so when we move to 64-bit computing, which DVI ... package supports these same hyperlink options?

Are there any macro packages for TeX like the LaTeX package `hyperref?`

Are there any good examples / manuals so that I can easily get control of how produce my own links, etc.?  I am interested in being able to insert various 'pdf' type features into our publications and almanacs going into the future.

Comment: I take it you don't need driver independence: is an answer that hard-codes `dvips` use acceptable? (I presume you'll be sticking to a DVI -> PS -> PDF route.)

Comment: I am looking for the best way forward.  I/we have a huge investment in TeX (no LATeX), producing very specialist material.  We currently include some eps graphics and some shading.  I am interested in getting a solution which include what we areleady have (even if there needs to be some changes), but also all the pdf capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the catalogue, the only recent thing i can find is [the `navigator` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) (a fairly recent thing; i thought there was another, but i can't currently find it).  the documentation of `navigator` looks fairly promising.

Comment: following joseph's comment, i would point out that `navigator` requires `pdftex`, `xetex` or `luatex`.  it _doesn't_ work with unadorned `tex`.